# Using Tonelli - upper and lower limits of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Given $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$ and a triangle $A$ with the corner points $$(0,0),(0,1),(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$$ how do I compute $$\int_A fd\lambda^2$$ I know I have to use Tonelli, but do I have to split the triangles into two triangles or how can I use Tonelli straightforward? Some help and explanation would be appreciated, especially when it comes to finding the lower and upper limits of the integral..

Comment: Technically you don't have to use Tonelli's theorem. But directly computing a multiple integral over an arbitrary region can be quite difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, there exists $(x^\star,y^\star)\in A$ with $$M:=f(x^\star,y^\star)=\sup_{(x,y)\in A}f(x,y).$$
$f$ is nonnegative, so we have $$\int_A f\ \mathsf d\lambda^2\leqslant M\lambda^2(A)<\infty, $$ and hence $f\in L^2(A)$. The assumptions of Tonelli's theorem are satisfied, so we may compute the double integral as an iterated integral:
\begin{align}
\int_A f\ \mathsf d\lambda^2 &= \iint\limits_A f(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^{\frac12}\int_0^y(x^2+y^2)\mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy+\int_{\frac12}^1\int_0^{1-y}(x^2+y^2)\mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac1{48} + \frac1{16}\\
&= \frac1{12}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also started by splitting it into two double integrals, somehow I miscalculated it three times. Good to know I was on the right path..

Comment: Also thanks for the detailed explanation why we are actually allowed to use Tonelli's theorem!

Comment: @Sigma It just takes practice :)